# Как нарисовать линию через центр круга?

Tags: c#, .net

Как реализовать так, чтобы линия проходила через центр, а не так как на скриншоте? Есть более лаконичные варианты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void drawLine(Double ex, Double ey, Double x, Double y)
    {
        var line = new Line();
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

        line.X1 = ex;
        line.X2 = x;
        line.Y1 = ey;
        line.Y2 = y;

        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        CanvasPhoto.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

Comment: вы рисуете в верхний левый угол, а не в центр. просто к координатам добавите половину от радиуса шара. пример, `line.X1 = ex` -> `line.X1 = ex + r / 2`, где `r` — радиус сферы.

Comment: также обычно пишут `line.X1 = ...; line.Y1 = ...; line.X2 = ...; line.Y2 = ...;`. т.е. вы инициализируете сперва иксы, а потом игреки, а лучше сперва 1-ю точку, а потом — 2-ю.